# Can't add ManyToMany relation in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have following model created in Django:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False, default='name')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, default='summary')
    description = models.TextField(blank = True, max_length=5000, default = LOREM_IPSUM)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rules = models.TextField(blank = True, default='rule set')
    parent = models.ManyToManyField(to = 'self', related_name="child", symmetrical = False, blank=True)
```

I added four `Content` objects through Django admin:

```
Project1
Task1
Task2
Task3
```

And set `parent` to `Project1` for all `TaskX`. When I want to display all the content with detailed `parent` atrribute it turns out to be `None`.

**views.py**

```
def display_ideas(request):
    ideas = Content.objects.filter(name="Task3")
    return render(request, 'display_ideas.html', context = { 'ideas' : ideas })
```

** display_ideas.html **

```
<div class="container bg-success">
{% for idea in ideas %}
    <div class="container bg-danger">
      <h2>Name:</h2>
        {{ idea.name }} has parent: {{ idea.parent.name }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

The output is:

**Name:**

Task3 has parent: None

What am I doing wrong? All migrations are done and the site is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a ManyToMany field content object may have more than 1 parent, thats why `{{ idea.parent.name }}` Does not work. You would have to iterate through each parent as you have done here for ideas `{% for idea in ideas %}`, to show the parent attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `parent` is a `ManyToManyField` and you can't access it directly so try to use nested loop so:

```py
<div class="container bg-success">
{% for idea in ideas %}
    <div class="container bg-danger">
      <h2>Name:</h2>
        {{ idea.name }} has parent(s): 
        {% for parent in idea.parent.all %}
            {{ parent.name }},
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```